# display query result after inserting

Tags: php, codeigniter

please help me how to display data to the view page after insert query into database.

view page(member_view.php):

```
<form action="<?php member_controller/insert_info; ?>" method="post">
<input type="text" name="fname">  
<input type="text" name="lname">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>  

<?php 
if($res){
    foreach($res as $data){
    echo $data['fname'];  
    echo $data['lname'];
    }
}
?>
```

controller page(member_controller.php):

```
<?php  
class Member_Controller extends CI_Controller {

public function insert_info(){  

$data = array('fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),  
'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),           
);  

$this->load->model('member_model');  
$this->member_model->member_posting($data);  
$data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
$retrieved_info['res'] = $this->member_model->member_posting($data);
$this->load->view('member_view',$data, $retrieved_info)
}

}
```

model page(member_model):

```
<?php
class Member_Model extends CI_Model{  

public function member_posting($data=array()){

extract($data);

$query = "INSERT INTO member_table (fname, lname)values ('$fname', '$lname')";
$result = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($query);
$result->execute();

if($result){
$query = "SELECT * FROM member_table WHERE fname = '$fname' AND lname='$lname'";
$result = $this->db->conn_id->prepare($query);
$result->execute();   
return $res = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

}

}
```

and here would be the pattern:

view(submit form)---->controller(get vars and send to model) --->
model(insert to db and perform select query)--->controller(get the select query results from model)--->view(display the results)

please help me, im just new to codeigniter, hope i can learn from you guys.

Answer (score 1):

This is the way you need to follow.........

View file:member_view.php

```
<form action="<?php echo ROOT_FOLDER ?>/member_controller/insert_info" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="fname">  
  <input type="text" name="lname">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Controller file: member_controller.php

```
<?php  
     class Member_Controller extends CI_Controller {

        public function insert_info()

         {  

           $data = array(
                      'fname' => $this->input->post('fname'),  
                      'lname' => $this->input->post('lname'),           
                   );  

          $this->load->model('member_model');  
          $this->member_model1->member_posting($data);
          $retrieved_info = array();
          $retrieved_info['res'] = $this->member_model2->member_posting($data);
          $this->load->view('member_view',$data, $retrieved_info)
       }

   }
```

Model file: member_model1.php

```
      class Member_Model extends CI_Model{  

        public function member_posting_inserting($data){

          $this->insert_helper('member_table',$data); 

         }

        public function member_posting_retrieving($data){

           $query = "SELECT * FROM member_table WHERE fname = '$data['fname']' AND lname='$data['lname']'";
           $res=$this->db->query($query);

            if($res->num_rows()>0){
             return $res->result("array");
             }
           return array();
         }  
       }
```

Insert helper function...............

```
   public function insert_helper($table_name, $data_array){
    $this->db->insert($table_name,$data_array);
    return $this->db->insert_id();      
}
```

Comment: hi Venkat, where should i place public function insert_helper?

Comment: $this->load->model('member_model');  
$this->member_model->member_posting($data);  
$data['username'] = $session_data['username'];
$data['res'] = $this->member_model->member_posting($data); 
$this->load->view('member_view',$data); this is what i did. its working.. still, thanks for your time and effort..

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$this->load->view('member_view',$data, $retrieved_info)
```

in your case won't do the trick. Read about the views here: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/views.html

2nd parameter is data array. 3rd parameter can be TRUE or FALSE, deciding if the view has to be rendered or returned as string.

This should do the trick:

```
$this->load->view('member_view', $retrieved_info);
```

Edit:

Just noticed your member_posting() doesn't return anything. It should return $res;